# Music/Sound Visualizer. How to determine noise level?

Tags: audio

I would like to make a music visualizer, but I need to know the intensity of the music playing. The music is playing from my Pi, so if this is possible without a mic that would be great but I'm assuming it's not. Is there a command line tool that returns the audio intensity from the mic at a given time?

Comment: Take a look at [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) and [Marsyas](http://marsyas.info/). Also look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703128/real-time-audio-analysis-in-linux). I'm not sure if any of these could work on the Pi. Perhaps you should also add more details on the software you are using to play the music.

Comment: [This](http://freshfoo.com/blog/pulseaudio_monitoring) seems almost exactly like what you need.